# Find Infimum and supremum of a set $A=\{ \sqrt[n^2]{(n^2+2n+1)^2}:n\in \mathbb{N}\} $

Tags: calculus

I have to find Infimum and supremum of a set $A=\{ \sqrt[n^2]{(n^2+2n+1)^2}:n\in \mathbb{N}\} $. I tied to do this by finding extrema of the function
$$
f(x)=(x+1)^{\tfrac{2}{x^2}}=\exp(\tfrac{2}{x^2}\log(x+1)) \qquad x>0
$$
and i tried to find extrema of the function inside exponent but I can't find x for which it's derivative is equal to $0$. My computations are
$$
\frac{2}{x^2(x+1)}+\frac{-4\log(x+1)}{x^3}=0
$$
$$
\frac{2}{(x+1)}-\frac{4\log(x+1)}{x}=0
$$
$$
\frac{2x-4(x+1)\log(x+1)}{(x+1)x}=0
$$
$$
2x-4(x+1)\log(x+1)=0
$$
and I don't know what to do next. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $x$ is sufficiently big, for example, when $x>e-1$, we have $(\ln(f(x)))'=\frac{2x-4(x+1)\log(x+1)}{x^3(x+1)}<\frac{2x-4(x+1)}{x^3(x+1)}<0$. So $f(x)$ is monotonically decreasing when $x>e-1$. So $\sup A$ equals to one of the $a_n$ where $n\leq e-1$.
On the other hand, since $\ln(f(x))$ is monotonically decreasing when $x$ is big enough, and that $f$ is continuous, $\inf A=e^{\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\ln(f(x))}=e^0=1$.